# Free android app that can RECEIVE sms messages

Tags: android, ios

I need an app that can receive sms's for free on android or possibly iOS to sign up for services. All the free apps are the two same apps reposted and actually cost money or don't receive SMS's, only send them. The ratings and download number are also very positive regardless of the apps being a scam. Does someone know of a legitimate app that I download and receive SMS's to a phone number that doesn't cost money?

Comment: Just curious - what's wrong with your 'phone's built in SMS app? Or are you asking for an app which also provides a 'phone number? If so, please update your question; thanks

Comment: @Mawg, I didn't have a phone that worked in the country I was in and needed a wifi phone.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining (+1). You might want to update your question to make it clearer. What you are after is probably *not* an SMS an SMS app. SMS can only be sent over the telephone network, to your Directory Number, which is associated with your SIM card, which you have said that you cannot use in the country where you are/will be ... ->

Comment: Which leaves you two options 1) an app like WhatsApp, which can ne used on WiF, or 2) such an app, but it will write any messages received to your ‘phone’s SMS data and will somehow manage to convert whatever you send to an SMS before delivering it. The latter can only be achieved by sing a server somewhere, which generates SMS message. It cannot be done in ‘phone only, using WiFi ... ->

Comment: Are you just looking for a chat app? Or must it look like SMS, both receiving and sending?  Would you accept an app which requires those with whom you communicate to install it too, or not? If not, is your ‘phone iOS or Android (lose the other tag)? Must if be free, or do you have a budget? My is to get a cheap second hand Android ‘phone and pout you SIM in it, for simplicity's sake; send & receive SMS as normal and use WifI calling with Skype, Viper, WhatsApp, etc

Answer (score 1):

After trying about ~20 apps. FreedomPop is the first phone app on android that worked for free to receive an SMS. Google's app turned out to be junk- Wouldn't advance past the opening screen. I have successfully signed up for services now using FreedomPop so the numbers are recognized online.

It's called [text free & call free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freedompop.ott&hl=en) in the store but named freedompop after you install it and has a medium (3.9) score which shows ratings don't appear to mean much sometimes. The app that is titled Myfreedompop in the store is apparently a scam that charges you without asking so be careful to pick this one(at least this version has worked today).

---

Update: Found another app that worked and received SMS: TextNow android app.
Update 2: Found a third app that worked: textFree

The number can be used for a month on these free which is more than I need just to receive an SMS verification message.